# How to change class on click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I trying to change the CSS class asigned to a element on click event but can't see which is the selector I must use in my case. See I have a DL with some DD inside, the first DD have class="active" and I need to remove this class when I pick any other DD and asign the class to the DD picked up, understand? A bit example:

```
<dl>
  <dd class="active">DD1</dd>
  <dd>DD2</dd>
  <dd>DD3</dd>
</dl>
```

If I pick DD2 then class="active" should dissapear from DD1 and move to DD2 and so on. I think in use :eq() but though doesn't work. Any advice or help?

EDIT: Sample is ready!!
Goes to http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/ and login as demo/demo123 and then go to "Directorio" you will see Filters and beside letters "A", "B" and so on, as you can see A is default and have active class but pick "B" or any other and see what's happeninng, this is what I'm refer before!

Cheers and thanks

Comment: Cursory research will bring up lots of resources for this. Did you search? Look into jQuery's `on()` and `toggleClass()` methods.

Comment: Of course I did research before ask here but can't get my code works because of that I ask for help @Utkanos

Answer (score 4):

```
$('dd').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/58yFW/)

Comment: is very rare because your code works at JSFiddle but mine doesn't and I just copy & paste nothing else! I'll upload files to somewhere and leave links here in some minutes

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript does change the link on click, but this is not necessary in your scenario:

```
$("dd").click(function(){
    $("dd").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

You should rather do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var letter = window.location.pathname.slice(-1);
    $("dd").removeClass("active");
    $("dl.sub-nav dd a:contains("+letter+")").parent().addClass("active");
});
```

It's still hacky, it would be better to set the class to the currently selected letter in the server side script.

Comment: it works but temporary because the active class goes back to the first element meaning DD1 the same occurs with the others code

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to remove the class if you click on the active element itself?

Comment: no I wan't to remove the class from the default element which is the first one DD1 and asign to the element clicked meaning DD2 or DD3 or even DD1 if is the case

Comment: OK, now i see what's going on. After you click, the page is reloaded completely, and the changes you made by the JavaScript so no longer apply. I will edit my answer into something useful for you.